# How to load two values from different array as a result of searchController?

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I have to arrays which populates the values of searchController.

```
let textLabel = ["Uni", "Uni", "Faber-Castell", "Faber-Castell","Faber-Castell", "Pilot", "Pilot"]
let detailTextLabel = ["Pen", "Pencil", "Crayon", "Mechanical Pencil", "Contour Pencil", "Eraser", "Sharpener"]
```

These two arrays pair while reloading the data of `UITableViewController.` Like (Uni, Pen), (Uni, Pencil), (Faber-Castell, Crayon) ...

In pairs, first one is the cell title, second one is the subtitle. I followed [iOSCreator's tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift).

My problem is when I search text it only updates title section, not the subtitle as it was expected.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // 3
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
    // it only updates textLabel. But when I add detailTextLabel 
    // subtitles comes wrong because first array contains one element
    // more than twice.
      cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

      return cell
    } else {
      cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

      return cell
    }
  }

  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Comment: Check Apple's UISearchController source code.

Answer (score -1):

Use the single array like this:

```
let penList = ["Uni:Pen", "Uni:Pencil", "Faber-Castell:Crayon"]

let result = filteredTableData[indexPath.row] // example: "Uni:Pen"
let clearResult = String(result.characters.map { $0 == ":" ? " " : $0 })
// clearResult like this "Uni Pen"
cell.textLabel?.text = clearResult
```

Also you can get data seperated

```
let result = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
let resultArray = result.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
let firstText = resultArray[0] // title text
let secondText = resultArray[1] // subtitle text
```

Comment: I think you skipped subtitle.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You are artificially making strings containing different values that you have to split later anyway (which is expensive, and convoluted). Use structs/classes/tuples to hold pair of values instead.

Comment: But what if I have too much values? I mean about a thousand values which cannot be typed by hand. @EricD

Comment: @ardakaraca Exactly, this solution is not good, not only it would force you to assemble the strings by hand but it is convoluted and inefficient anyway. // How do you get your values in the arrays currently? Just do the same but embed each values in a struct (with a loop or anything appropriate) and make an array of the structs. Then you can filter the array at your convenience.